# Python time library - imprecision in time evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Out of curiosity, I wanted to see the imprecision of time evaluation in Python using `time` module.

As I know that functions like `time.time()` and time.sleep()` are based on the CPU clock, what I expected was some more or less random imprecision in the evaluation of time.

As a first experiment, I ran:

```
import time

mean_1 = 0.0
print("Waiting for 0.5 second 10 times...")
for i in range(10):
    start = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end - start
    print(str(i) + ': ' + str(elapsed_time) + ' s')
    mean_1 = mean_1 + elapsed_time
mean_1 = mean_1/10.0
print("----------")
print("Mean time overhead when waiting for 0.5 second : " + str(mean_1 - 0.5) + " s")
```

Which output:

```
Waiting for 0.5 second 10 times...
0: 0.5008149147033691 s
1: 0.5005350112915039 s
2: 0.500540018081665 s
3: 0.5006759166717529 s
4: 0.5008018016815186 s
5: 0.5007147789001465 s
6: 0.5005414485931396 s
7: 0.5008261203765869 s
8: 0.5005924701690674 s
9: 0.5007064342498779 s
----------
Mean time overhead when waiting for 0.5 second : 0.0006748914718628 s
```

First thing I thought was that even with CPU clock imprecision, a mean of 675 µs is quite important for a CPU working at nanometer scale.

However, something is very clear in the results: the overhead is very stable for every loop step. So I concluded that this was probably due to the execution time of `time.time()`, which is included in the global time evaluation.

To be sure, I tried with different sleep times:

```
import time

mean_1 = 0.0
mean_2 = 0.0
mean_3 = 0.0
print("Waiting for 0.5 second 10 times...")
for i in range(10):
    start = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end - start
    print(str(i) + ': ' + str(elapsed_time) + ' s')
    mean_1 = mean_1 + elapsed_time
mean_1 = mean_1/10.0
print("----------")

print("Waiting for 1 second 10 times...")
for i in range(10):
    start = time.time()
    time.sleep(1.0)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end - start
    print(str(i) + ': ' + str(elapsed_time) + ' s')
    mean_2 = mean_2 + elapsed_time
mean_2 = mean_2/10.0
print("----------")

print("Waiting for 2.0 seconds 10 times...")
for i in range(10):
    start = time.time()
    time.sleep(2.0)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end - start
    print(str(i) + ': ' + str(elapsed_time) + ' s')
    mean_3 = mean_3 + elapsed_time
mean_3 = mean_3/10.0
print("----------")
print("Mean time overhead when waiting for 0.5 second : " + str(mean_1 - 0.5) + " s")
print("Mean time overhead when waiting for 1.0 second : " + str(mean_2 - 1.0) + " s")
print("Mean time overhead when waiting for 2.0 seconds : " + str(mean_3 - 2.0) + " s")
```

Which output:

```
Waiting for 0.5 second 10 times...
0: 0.5007686614990234 s
1: 0.5005531311035156 s
2: 0.5007860660552979 s
3: 0.500603199005127 s
4: 0.5007908344268799 s
5: 0.5007991790771484 s
6: 0.5006780624389648 s
7: 0.5008070468902588 s
8: 0.5007193088531494 s
9: 0.5008025169372559 s
----------
Waiting for 1 second 10 times...
0: 1.0012505054473877 s
1: 1.001307725906372 s
2: 1.001314640045166 s
3: 1.0013072490692139 s
4: 1.0011889934539795 s
5: 1.0013320446014404 s
6: 1.0011751651763916 s
7: 1.0012929439544678 s
8: 1.0013163089752197 s
9: 1.001300573348999 s
----------
Waiting for 2.0 seconds 10 times...
0: 2.002312183380127 s
1: 2.0020830631256104 s
2: 2.002326011657715 s
3: 2.0023014545440674 s
4: 2.0022478103637695 s
5: 2.002275228500366 s
6: 2.002082347869873 s
7: 2.0020837783813477 s
8: 2.0023083686828613 s
9: 2.0023066997528076 s
----------
Mean time overhead when waiting for 0.5 second : 0.0007308006286621538 s
Mean time overhead when waiting for 1.0 second : 0.0012786149978638583 s
Mean time overhead when waiting for 2.0 seconds : 0.0022326946258544034 s
```

So if my theory had been right, `time.time()` execution time being independent of `time.sleep()` execution time, the overhead would have been the same for 1.0 and 2.0 seconds.

However, the overhead seems proportional with sleep time. So my conclusion was: there seem to be a quite important, positive, bias in the evaluation of time.

So my questions (finally) are:

1. *What causes such a bias in time evaluation while standard deviation seems very small compared to it?*
2. *Is there an embedded way to calibrate time evaluation on a given system to automatically remove this bias?*

A few (probably) useful details about the experiment parameters:

- i7-8850U
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Python-3.5.2

Comment: This sounds more like an oversleep proportional to requested sleep time than a bias in time evaluation.

Comment: Yes, but I guess the time base for the whole `time` module is the same, so time evaluation could be also concerned.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I tell people to rely on the OS (ie cron) for scheduling rather than on `time.sleep`.